# Skyline of Buildings

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to understand the skyline problem. Given `n` rectangular building and we need to compute the skyline. I have trouble in understanding the output for this problem.

> Input: (1,11,5), (2,6,7), (3,13,9), (12,7,16), (14,3,25), (19,18,22), (23,13,29), (24,4,28) }
>
> Output Skylines: (1, 11), (3, 13), (9, 0), (12, 7), (16, 3), (19, 18), (22, 3), (25, 0)

The output is pair `(xaxis, height)`. Why is the third pair `(9,0)`? If we see the skyline graph, the x-axis value 9 has height of 13, not 0. Why is it showing 0? In other words, if we take the first building (input `(1,11,5)`), the output is `(1, 11)`, `(5, 0)`. Can you guys explain why it is `(5,0)` instead of `(5,11)`?

Comment: You should post a [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-7-the-skyline-problem/) to the problem, for those who don't know what the skyline problem is.

Comment: Check out my blog post on this problem. https://briangordon.github.io/2014/08/the-skyline-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

Think of the rooftop intervals as closed on the left and open on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your output does not signify "at x the height is y", but rather "at x the height changes to y".

Answer (score 0):

using the sweep line algorithm; here is my python version solution:

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer[][]} buildings
    # @return {integer[][]}
    def getSkyline(self, buildings):
        if len(buildings)==0: return []
        if len(buildings)==1: return [[buildings[0][0], buildings[0][2]], [buildings[0][1], 0]]

        points=[]
        for building in buildings:
            points+=[[building[0],building[2]]]
            points+=[[building[1],-building[2]]]
        points=sorted(points, key=lambda x: x[0])

        moving, active, res, current=0, [0], [],-1

        while moving<len(points):
            i=moving
            while i<=len(points):
                if i<len(points) and points[i][0]==points[moving][0]:
                    if points[i][1]>0:
                        active+=[points[i][1]]
                        if points[i][1]>current:
                            current=points[i][1]
                            if len(res)>0 and res[-1][0]==points[i][0]: 
                                res[-1][1]=current
                            else:
                                res+=[[points[moving][0], current]]
                    else:
                        active.remove(-points[i][1])
                    i+=1
                else:
                    break

            if max(active)<current:
                current=max(active)
                res+=[[points[moving][0], current]] 
            moving=i
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static long largestRectangle(int[] h) {

    int k=1;
    int n=h.length;
    long max=0;

    while(k<=n){

        long area=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n-k+1;i++){
            long min=Long.MAX_VALUE;
            
            for(int j=i;j<i+k;j++){

                //System.out.print(h[j]+" ");
                min=Math.min(h[j],min);
            }
           // System.out.println();
            area=k*min;
            //System.out.println(area);
            max=Math.max(area,max);
        }
        //System.out.println(k);
        k++;
    }
    return max;
}
```